# jQuery isotope: Lock the position of specific items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using jQuery Isotope to lay out a list of file entries contained in an `<ol>` element. I would like to keep Isotope from moving several items at the beginning of this list, such as an item indicating a parent folder. If I sort those elements using Isotope, the "parent" entry will be moved around which is very annoying.

Is there any way to tell Isotope not to change an item's position apart from "tweaking" the sort rules to assign a special sort index to it? This is the way it works now, but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

If needed I can provide a simplified jsFiddle test case.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked quite some time ago, and maybe back then the functionality wasn't available.

I just stumbled upon it and wanted to add that there's a "stamp" functionality, that tells isotope to layout the items around the "stamped" element.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#stamp

> Stamps elements in the layout. Isotope will lay out item elements
>   around stamped elements.

```
// jQuery
$grid.isotope( 'stamp', elements )
// vanilla JS
iso.stamp( elements )
```